# How to combine regular expressions for matching strings with and without delimiters?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have strings like the following ones mentioned as ***Input*** that need to be processed and transformed into `name`/`value` pairs as indicated below:

***Input:*** `FOO = BAR=BAZ`
***Output:*** `name='FOO', value='BAR=BAZ'`

***Input:*** `FOO = BAR`
***Output:*** `name='FOO', value='BAR'`

***Input:*** `FOO =`
***Output:*** `name='FOO', value=''`

***Input:*** `= BAR=BAZ`
***Output:*** `name='', value='BAR:BAZ'`

***Input:*** `= BAR`
***Output:*** `name='', value='BAR'`

***Input:*** `FOO`
***Output:*** `name='FOO', value=''`

Note that the delimiter is either `=` or `:`. Having no delimiter is also possible.

The following code covers all above-mentioned cases except the last one,

```
regexp {^\s*(.*?)\s*[=:]\s*(.*?)\s*$} $setting -> name value

if {![info exists name]} {
    set name {}
}

if {![info exists value]} {
    set value {}
}

puts "name='$name', value='$value'"
```

for which it returns

***Output:*** `name='', value=''`

instead of

***Output:*** `name='FOO', value=''`

The last case could be covered by the regular expression below:

```
regexp {^\s*(.*?)\s*$} $setting -> name value
```

How those regular expressions could be combined to just have a single regular expression covering all the cases?

Comment: Another suggestion: The `[info exists]` tests are not necessary, all sub-match variables will be set to an empty string (if unmatched for whatever reason).

Comment: Yes, indeed, they are not necessary when using the regular expression you suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you insist on doing this with `regexp`. When your regular expression becomes too complicated, it may be time to use a different approach. Assuming there won't be any NUL characters in your string, you could do this instead:

```
lassign [split [regsub {\s*[:=]\s*} [string trim $setting] \0] \0] name value
```

The string trim gets rid of any surrounding white space. Then the delimiter and any surrounding white space is replaced by a NUL character. Finally the result is broken in two on that NUL character and the two parts are assigned to the name and value variables.

According to my measurements, this method is more than twice as fast as the regexp variant.

Answer (score 1):

> How those regular expressions could be combined to just have a single regular expression covering all the cases?

The former already includes the latter :) But your more extensive regex cannot match the last case (`FOO`) because it does not contain the delimiter characters at all. Watch the result of the `[regexp]`, which will be `0`.

Consider the following:

```
 ^\s*([^=:]*)\s*[=:]?\s*(.*)\s*$
```

This should have all cases covered, even the value-only (RHS-only) case.

Answer (score 1):

```
set tests {{FOO = BAR=BAZ} {FOO = BAR} {FOO =} {= BAR=BAZ} {= BAR} FOO}
foreach test $tests {
    # expanded regex with commentary
    regexp {(?x)
        (.*?)               # the left-hand side, may be empty
        (?:                 # start a group, but do not capture it
            \s*[:=]\s*      # the separator
            (.*)            # the value
        )?                  # end the group, and it is optional
        $                   # until the end of line: this is required because the
                            # whole regex is non-greedy due to the first
                            # quantifier being non-greedy. Without the anchor,
                            # the 2nd capture will always be the empty string.
    } $test -> var value

    puts "name='$var', value='$value'"
}
```

outputs

```
name='FOO', value='BAR=BAZ'
name='FOO', value='BAR'
name='FOO', value=''
name='', value='BAR=BAZ'
name='', value='BAR'
name='FOO', value=''
```